# Network monitor in openwrt

Tags: python, scapy, tcpdump, openwrt

I'm using tcpdump in openwrt to capture all wifi packets sent (Probe request/response and etc..)

```
tcpdump -i mon0 -e -tt
```

But the packets i capture doesn't have all the data i looking for e.g the channel of the packet

So i tried to save it to a pcap file

```
tcpdump -i mon0 -w capture.pcap
```

and then i loaded this pcap in Wireshark and all the missing data was there
But when i tried to parse it in Python i didn't managed to find that data.

Does some know the best way to capture all the packet data?

Comment: What data are you looking for, other than the channel?

Comment: source mac address, rssi, destination

Comment: What does the command `tcpdump -L -i mon0` print?

Comment: Data link types for mon0 (use option -y to set):
  IEEE802_11_RADIO (802.11 plus radiotap header)

Answer (score 0):

> Data link types for mon0 (use option -y to set): IEEE802_11_RADIO (802.11 plus radiotap header)

Then the raw packet data will begin with a [radiotap header](http://www.radiotap.org), which has fields that, if present, indicate:

- the channel ([Channel](http://www.radiotap.org/defined-fields/Channel), which contains the channel frequency, not the channel number, or [XChannel](http://www.radiotap.org/suggested-fields/XChannel), which contains both - the header might have both Channel *and* XChannel)
- the signal strength, in dBm ([Antenna signal](http://www.radiotap.org/defined-fields/Antenna%20signal)), or the signal strength, in dB from some arbitrary reference point ([dB antenna signal](http://www.radiotap.org/defined-fields/dB%20antenna%20signal)).

Be warned that radiotap headers are not simple to parse.

The radiotap header has a length field, which is a little-endian value, at the beginning; it indicates how long the entire header, including all the fields, is.

After the radiotap header, there will be an 802.11 header, which will contain the source and destination MAC addresses.  See [the IEEE 802.11 specification](http://standards.ieee.org/about/get/802/802.11.html).

Comment: and the information elements will be after the 802.11 header?

Comment: The information elements are components of 802.11 management frames, so they're in the body of the management frame, which follows the header.  See the IEEE 802.11 specification.  (Parsing 802.11 management frames is *also* not simple.)  When you say "parse it in Python", do you mean writing Python code to parse the raw packet data, or are you using something such as [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/)?

Comment: I'm exactly starting to use Scapy for this

Comment: After trying to use Scapy i noticed that he capture much less packet then tcpdump, is it a known issue?

Comment: Captures fewer packets, or captures the same packets but doesn't capture all the data in the packet ("captured length" less than "actual length")?

Comment: Capture fewer, i compared the Scapy to Microsoft Network Monitor and found that Scapy capture less then the Microsoft Network Monitor, in less i mean the amount of packets, not the packet lenght

Comment: So Scapy captures fewer packets than tcpdump does *and* captures fewer packets than Microsoft Network Monitor does?  (Presumably you're running Network Monitor on another machine, on the same machine after booting Windows on that machine, or on a virtual machine, as it doesn't run on Linux.)

Comment: Yes the Network Monitor running on another machine that is placed next to the one running scapy

Answer (score 0):

When you used `tcpdump -i mon0 -e -tt` command, `tcpdump` read raw data used libcap and convert to readable info print on console. During this, some information may dropped.

You can check the source code of [Tcpdum](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump) to get more thing.

Also try `-vvv` parameter to get more verbose output.

Answer (score 0):

I referred this link, I think this will solve your query.

https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=54048

I used info given in above link, but I want to know that which IP address is accessing which website, without any additional package installation, just add 3 lines in /etc/dnsmasq.conf file i.e.

```
log-queries             
log-facility=/root/dnslog.txt       
log-async=10
```

and restart dnsmasq(/etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart)
You will find your log file in your root directory.